# grafana- get values from dashboard with mysql as data source with API

Tags: api, prometheus, grafana, grafana-api

I am trying to extract values from the dashboard from Grafana Dashboard. I have MySQL as data source and I have a query to extract values from a particular table in MySQL.

I am trying to get these values shown on dashboard with some API.

For prometheus, I have came across this API of [Instant Queries](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/1.8/querying/api/#instant-queries) and it works well. Similarly I want to get the for grafana dashboard. I went through these Grafana [HTTP APIs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/http_api), but did not find any to get mysql records displayed on dashboard.

Are there any other APIs? Or any other way to get these records?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found was to:

1. Open the dashboard and then inspect the panel
2. Open the query tab and click on `refresh`
3. Use the url and parameters on your own query to the api

*note*: First you need to create an API key in the UI with the proper role and add the `bearer` to the request headers

Comment: Thank you for responding. I found a way to get those values using selenium and "Chro Path Utility" which I have mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to extract the record. It is using "Chro Path Utility", get the XPath  for needed row/column/cell and use them in your Selenium code.

Answer (score 0):

emmmm, i found that is chrome problem, which cant add custom header...
replace with PHANTOMJS that it work.
bur PHANTOMJS cant see full data(download png see that)....

......................

oh, can you tell me how do that?
i use selenium but cant get the data...that is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')    

url="http://<IP:PORT>/d/SsYvTg6Wk/rights?orgId=1&from=now-1h&to=now" 
#url copy from browser chrome

browser=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver", chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.header_overrides = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer xxx'
}
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
browser.get(url)
# browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
browser.find_element_by_id('flotGagueValue0')
```